# Attempting to access prior repo on Heroku

Tags: heroku, git

I made a push to Heroku (using the CLI) with corrupted code and was able to roll back the production to the right version. After trying git pull to access the current repo locally, heroku only updated with the latest (corrupted) version. How do I access the previous repo?

I tried `heroku releases -n 50` to locate the previous repo, but when I attempted `git pull heroku <branch>` I received the error `fatal: couldn't find remote ref 0fc3f878`. I have attached screenshots for reference, v29 was the desired repo. Greatly appreciate any advice. [image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Important distinction: what you're talking about are *commits*, not *repos*. You have a local repo where your code is stored, and you have a Heroku remote to which you push commits. in order to perform a deploy.

`0fc3f878` is the SHA hash corresponding to the commit in your *local* repo that was pushed. You should be able to access it by doing `git checkout 0fc3f878`. This will result in your local repo being in "detached HEAD" state, where you're not following a specific branch.

What you may wish to do instead is *revert* the two commits that follow `0fc3f878` in your local history, via `git revert`. This will add new commits to your repo that undo the changes introduced in those commits, while preserving the full history of your project, and your ability to access those changes if you later wish to work on them again.